# How to make a sync force in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronization

I am writing a js lib, that consume services from a server (BE). I am using Jquery - AJAX to consume those services. However, to consume this server I need to set callback for success/error

```
function CallAjax(callback){

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://server.com/service1.svc',
  success: function(data) {
        callback(data);
      }
});

}
```

So that I need to wait for the callback to return the proper value, but **do** function has already return to main page.

```
myLib = (function () {

   do = function ()
   {
       var callback = function() { return true };

          CallAjax(callback);
   }


 }())
```

main page: but I want to consume the my lib sync but from the nature of the call I do not fin the way to make it.

```
 I would like something like 
   if ( mylib.do() == true)
     { }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `async` switch to false. This will lead to a synchronous call to the server. Note though the consequences of this: the client browser will freeze during the execution of the request. If you don't want this to happen you will have to redesign your library so that it works with callbacks which IMHO is the correct way to work with AJAX. So provide callbacks to the consumer of your library.

Comment: And @Agus, you really don't want a synchronous AJAX setup if you can avoid it (and you can :-)

Comment: Completely agree with Pointy. I have mentioned the `async: false` switch just as an alternative, not as something that should ever be used.

Comment: ok, I got it, so work with callback is the way? it's a good practice?

Comment: Yes, that's the best practice.